# How do I allow access to SVN via WebDAV based on branches?

Tags: svn, webdav

I want to restrict the access of users to SVN repos by branch. The users would be accessing the repo via Apache / WebDAV. It's mostly about commits, I don't really care about the read access too much. Also, it's mostly about avoiding accidents, rather than distrusting users.

Note that I am just about to set up the WebDAV access, i. e. I'm still a noob on this. So far, I have read a few tutorials and could not find all the bits and pieces that I need. This question is one that's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html). There's no automatic way though to restrict access to all branches when you have a layout like:

```
projectA/trunk
projectA/branches
projectB/trunk
projectB/branches
```

It comes down to only giving certain people access to branches:

```
[groups]
calc-developers = harry, sally, joe

# Allow everyone read access
[/]
* = r

# Allow harry to write to branches
[calc:projectA/branches/]
harry = rw

# Allow calc-developers group RW access to trunk
[calc:projectA/trunk]
@calc-developers = rw
```